# as.matrix not preserving the data mode of an empty data.frame

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have found something odd today, I wanted to ask you if there was a logical reason for what I am seeing, or if you think this is a bug that should be reported to the R-devel team:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1L:10L)
class(df$a)
# [1] "integer"
m <- as.matrix(df)
class(m[, "a"])
# [1] "integer"
```

No surprise so far: `as.matrix` preserves the data mode, here "integer". However, with an empty (no rows) data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a = integer(0))
class(df$a)
# [1] "integer"
m <- as.matrix(df)
class(m[, "a"])
# [1] "logical"
```

Any idea why the mode changes from "integer" to "logical" here? I am using version 2.13.1

Thank you.

Comment: No idea why that happens, but you'd better test it on the latest snapshot before posting on R-devel.  They don't appreciate "bug reports" on 6-month old versions of R.

Comment: I get the same behavior here, R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22).

Comment: And I see the same thing in 2.14.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of this one line in `as.matrix.data.frame`:

```
if (any(dm == 0L)) return(array(NA, dim = dm, dimnames = dn))
```

Basically, if any dimensions are zero, you get an array "full" of `NA`.  I say "full" because there aren't really any observations because one of the dimensions is zero.

The reason the class is `logical` is because that's the class of `NA`.  There are special `NA` for other classes, but they're not really necessary here.  For example:

```
> class(NA)
[1] "logical"
> class(NA_integer_)
[1] "integer"
> class(NA_real_)
[1] "numeric"
> class(NA_complex_)
[1] "complex"
> class(NA_character_)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I wish I knew how to find my way into R's base code like you do. I stopped at `print(as.matrix)`...

Comment: @flodel: `print(as.matrix)` shows `UseMethod("as.matrix")`, so then I look at `methods(as.matrix)`.  Then you can use `print(as.matrix.data.frame)` to see the data.frame method.  If the method happens to be "non-visible", you can use `getAnywhere` (e.g. `getAnywhere("as.matrix.dist")`).

Comment: These will be very helpful to me in the future, thank you for the follow up Joshua.